# Static operator function in C# affecting the given arguments

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Suppose I have two classes in a namespace, internal class A, and public class B. Class A contains an integer, meanwhile class B contains a list of Class A.

I have the following function:

```
public static A operator -(A object_a)
    => new(-object_a.number);
```

And executing the following:

```
A obj = new(18);
Console.WriteLine(-obj.ToString()); //output: -18
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString()); //output: 18
```

Now the problem comes in class B, with the following function:

```
public static B operator -(B object_b)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < object_b.container.Count; i++)
          object_b.container[i] = -object_b.container[i]; //which is an object A

    return new(object_b.container); // the constructor for class B takes a list of class A objects
```

Executing:

```
Console.WriteLine((-object_b).ToString()); //Output: -18, -18, -18
Console.WriteLine(object_b.ToString()); //Output: -18, -18, -18
                                        //Expected output: 18, 18, 18
```

I tried to make a new object instead of returning the argument, but it gave the same output. Shouldn't a static function not affect its arguments? (The operator functions are implemented in their own classes, they are not extension methods).

Comment: "Shouldn't a static function not affect its arguments?" There is no such rule. You didn't copy the list, so no new list was created. The new B retuned by the operator is sharing the same list as the list that the original B had.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the method is static has nothing to do with whether or not changes to arguments are propagated back to the original values.

Your confusion comes from the fact that in your first example, the `A` constructor takes an `int`, which is a value type and is passed as a copy of the value.

However, in `B`, you are passing an object which will pass a *copy of the reference*. As a result, if you modify the inbound argument, it will be reflected back to the original caller.

As Sweeper mentioned in the comments, in this particular example, the simple solution is to copy the list before modifying it.

```
public static B operator -(B object_b)
{
    var copiedContainer = object_b.container.ToList();
    for(int i = 0; i < copiedContainer .Count; i++)
        copiedContainer [i] = -copiedContainer [i]; //which is an object A

    return new(copiedContainer); // the constructor for class B takes a list of class A objects
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't work :(

Comment: @Haydara doesn’t work how?

Comment: It gave the same output

Comment: @Haydara it isn’t clear what you mean. Can you update your question with the output you are getting vs what you expect?